# opening older 9.x Esri .gdb in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-9.3, file-geodatabase

I want to open an Esri .gdb with QGIS. I have adjusted GDAL and it works fine with an example .gdb provided on another thread on the topic. I still cannot open the .gdb of interest to me and suspect it is because it may not be a 10.something gdb, but probably an older .gdb file version. I have currently no access to Esri software. Anybody out there knowing a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The Esri File Geodatabase API library only supports 10.x FGDBs.  You cannot
access pre-10 file geodatabases from third-party applications.
The only solution is to use ArcGIS 10.x (Desktop or Python) to upgrade the FGDB.