# Bringing in ARC gdb into QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

Trying to bring in an ARC gdb folder into QGIS 3.16 using the Vector import tool but it keeps saying it is not a valid or recognised data source.

Layer -> add Layer -> Add Vector Layer
using directory with automatic encoding, OpenFileGDB as source type. Also tried using all of the other source types but no luck.

Everything I've found online says it can't be done - is this true?

Comment: Here is one that claims that it can be done for you https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html.

Comment: What does ogrinfo report?

Comment: Witch version your gbd are in ? Older version (9.x) are not supported see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70984/opening-older-9-x-esri-gdb-in-qgis

Comment: I use the ESRI file geodatabase option but I just tested the OpenFileGDB in response to your question.  When I pointed it to a geodatabase it said no items matched my search but I went ahead and selected the folder and then add layers anyway.  Then the individual layers showed up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `ctrl+shift+v` and in the opening dialog, select `database`. Then select proper `source` and `type` for the database. `Esri database` is one of the options and select `new` connection. Point to the directory which contains your desired DB, and `OK`. Now you're ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest way is to simply drag and drop the GDB directory into QGIS - it then automatically opens the layer import dialog box.